# Conflict in a FileDownload control in Notes 9 XPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am using this code placed in beforeRenderResponse event of an XPage in a notes 8.5.3 application:

```
function overrideFileDownloadAction( fDownload ){
   if( fDownload === null )
      return;
   rekOverrideFileDownloadAction( fDownload, fDownload );
}

function rekOverrideFileDownloadAction( component:javax.faces.component.UIOutput, fDownload:com.ibm.xsp.component.UIFileDownload ){
   try{
       var children:java.util.List = component.getChildren();
       var it:java.util.Iterator = children.iterator();
       var curChild:javax.faces.component.UIOutput;


       while( it.hasNext() ){
          curChild = it.next();
          if( typeof( curChild ) === 'com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler' ){
               var group = new com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup();
               var list = new java.util.ArrayList();
               group.setComponent( fDownload );
               list.add( curChild.getAction() );
               list.add( mBinding );
               group.setActions( list );
               curChild.setAction(group);
           }
           rekOverrideFileDownloadAction( curChild , fDownload );
        }
    }catch(e){}    
}

viewScope.flag_remove = false;
var code = "#{javascript:var fileDownload1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspFileDownload = getComponent('fileDownload1');var index = fileDownload1.getRowIndex(); if(viewScope.flag_remove == false){viewScope.types.removeElementAt(index); viewScope.flag_remove = true}}";
var mBinding = facesContext.getApplication().createMethodBinding(code, null );
overrideFileDownloadAction( getComponent( 'fileDownload1' ) );
```

I use this in order to save some info together with the file (i.e i have a drop down to select the type of file that i upload). So i want this info to be deleted and added together with the uploaded file.

I found the code above by googling and it works normally.

Now i installed Notes 9 and i want to test my app for potential issues.
I get this error:

> com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup incompatible with
>   com.ibm.xsp.actions.DeleteAttachmentsAction

when switching a document to edit mode.

Does anyone have the same problem? Any solutions?

Comment: So you are saying, that this code all worked normally in 8.5.3 and only started failing in 9.0?

Comment: Yes. And if i disable the delete feature the error does not appear again.

Comment: Sounds like something changed in V9. There are developers from the IBM XPages team that answer here, hopefully one of them will see this.

Comment: Yes, IBM has changed the delete action event, that's why you can't overwrite it anymore. I changed the way to process events of the file controls by catching the events in a phase listener. Here is an example: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1363